# Get element of nested arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a bunch of coordinates of some layers added to a map using leaflet. The coords are stored in arrays so when I'm pushing into a bigger one it results with nested arrays. Non I want to loop through each array and get the first and second element of each array.

My method is rendering me **cannot read property "1" of undefined**

```js
var coordsRep = []

var rep = new L.GeoJSON(reptiles, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    coordsRep.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);
  }
})

for (var i = 0; i < coordsRep.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < coordsRep[i].length; j++) {
    var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(coordsRep[i][j][1], coordsRep[i][j][0]);

    marker.category = AIRES_PROTEGEES;
    leafletView.RegisterMarker(marker);
  }
}
```

Comment: explain "_it didn't work_"

Comment: what is it you want to achieve? and is the depth of the nested array fixed or can it change?

Comment: Try to use jquery $.each() for more ref [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: @fesieg I want to get the first and second element of each nested array. Imagine I have 10 nested arrays with coordinates. So I want to get the x and y of each one and pass them to the Prunecluster.Marker().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both `i` and `j` in the indices, where `i` is the first index and `j` is the second:

```js
var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(coordsRep[i][j][1], coordsRep[i][j][0]);
```

Comment: I tried your method and I'm getting I cannot read property '1' of undefined